# How do you set <ul> bullet's list-style to a code decimal?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a `ul` that I want to set the bullet style of with the code decimal of `&#10003` (checkmark). Is there any way to do this? I tried `list-style-image`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to apply a workaround here:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
ul li:before { content: "\2713"; }
```

Then adapt padding and margin of ul, li and li:before to your liking. This won't work in IE < 8, though. There you will have to use images or JavaScript (or putting it in the markup, if you really need to support them).

Answer (score 0):

Closest you can likely get is something hacky like:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li:before {
content: "\2713";
}
```

Comment: "&#10003" doesn't work, since the value is taken literally. See my answer for the correct CSS escape syntax.

Comment: Yours didn't work before you edited it either, Boldewyn.  ;] Fixed, though.

Comment: Touché! But at last, I was the first with a working solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type through [`list-style-type`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style-type.asp) (however you're limited to the pre-set values, otherwise if you want to use [`list-style-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style-image.asp) you must supply an image, not a character.

Otherwise, use the `:before` selector as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731768/how-do-you-set-ul-bullets-list-style-to-a-code-decimal/5731823#5731823) have suggested.

Answer (score -2):

`list-style-type` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Nope. list-style-type can't display arbitrary characters.

Comment: Woops, my fault. I read it as a decimal number. `list-style-type: decimal;` is actually a valid call.

Comment: That's true. Errors occur ;-)